# Sencha touch xml reader

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a problem with sencha touch xmlreader.

find my code below

```
Ext.regModel('User', {
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'email']
});

var feedStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '192.168.248.1/notizie.xml',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'user'
        }
    }
});
```

notizie.xml

1
E
f

feedStore is always empty.

Could anyone can discover the reason?

Regards,

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you use JSON then you can use scripttag proxy or if you use native app wrapper like phonegap than you don't get that cross domain security issue.

Comment: Do you mean that ajax reuest outside the domain work using phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue!

If you use the ajax you just can send requests inside your domain.

I pubblished notizie.xml and index.html on the server.

My question is there is a way using sencha touch to make a request outside your domain?

Ragards,

Carmelo

Answer (score 0):

Only JSONP supports external domains. No way to use xml, only well formed json+callback. Look for ScriptTagProxy, it works pretty well, but only if you can change the service to use jsonp.

It's common policy with all current browsers. You can read more about this from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)